# Do I need ?wsdl in the URL when setting up SOAP?

Tags: c#, soap

I have inherited a NUnit test project and the code has the SOAP URL without `?wsdl` so the URL ends with  `../soap.svc`.
Authenticate is also missing `?wsdl` so the URL ends with `../WebServices/Authentication/Service.asmx`

Is the `?wsdl` added by default when the connection is being made?

Comment: I actually read loads on the subject but did not spot the distinction. I am new to C# and initiating services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wsdl` parameter is used when you want to get the actual WSDL definition file for the service, but not when you actually want to make service calls to the service. e.g.:

```
// GET or POST requests to call service functions.
http://localhost/Service/Service.asmx 

// GET the WSDL XML file for this service
http://localhost/Service/Service.asmx?wsdl
```

In general you probably should not have `?wsdl` on the end of the URL if you are expecting to interact with the service itself.

Answer (score 1):

Service.asmx - it is your endpoint

Service.asmx?wsdl - is documentation of your services.

If you are implementing client on .NET with "Create Web Reference" or "Create Service Reference" it accesses wsdl to collect necessary info about service and generate classes.